# how find the multiple erc20 token price right at the same time

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity

I can find single token price in one function call

```
contract.methods.getAmountsOut(arguments...);
```

but want to know how can i find the multiple token prices right at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Promise.all:

```
let prices = await Promise.all(tokens.map(token => contract.methods.getAmountsOut(token, ...arguments)))
```